# I cannot ping from my laptop to my desktop and vice-versa but can ping my smartphone

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ping

I have a router Netgear Nighthawk Model # R7000. Its web interface gives me this information:

- In the "***Internet Setup***" of router:

  - Internet IP Address is `Get Dynamically from ISP`
  - Domain Name Server (DNS) Address is `Get Automatically from ISP`
  - Router MAC Address is `Use Default Address`

- In the "***Wireless Setup***" of router, there are 2 Wireless network setup:

  1. *1st Wireless Network:*

     - It's type is `2.4GHz b/g/n`
     - `Enable SSID Broadcast` option is checked
     - Name (SSID) is `SRH-NETGEAR`
     - Channel is `Auto`
     - Mode is `Up to 600 Mbps`
  2. *2nd Wireless Network:*

     - It's type is `5GHz a/n/ac`
     - `Enable SSID Broadcast` option is checked
     - Name (SSID) is `SRH-NETGEAR-5G`
     - Channel is `153`
     - Mode is `Up to 1300 Mbps`

- In the "***LAN Setup***" of router:

  - *IP Address* is set to `198.168.1.1`
  - IP Subnet Mask is set to `255.255.255.0`
  - RIP Direction is set to `Both`
  - RIP Version is set to `Disabled`
  - `Use Router as DHCP Server` option is checked while Starting IP
    Address is `192.168.1.2` and Ending IP Address is `192.168.1.254`.

`Wireless AP mode` is not checked.

`Enable Wireless Repeating Function (2.4GHz b/g/n)` is not checked.

`Enable Wireless Repeating Function (5GHz a/n/ac)` is not checked.

---

I have a desktop PC. Its name is **Srh-PC**. Its operating system is Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1 64-bit. It is connected to **SRH-NETGEAR** as wireless for internet. Its IP Address is `192.168.1.10`. From the command prompt, I can ping the router 192.168.1.1.

---

I have a laptop. Its name is **Srh-HP**. Its operating system is Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1 64-bit. It is connected to **SRH-NETGEAR** as wireless for internet. Its IP Address is `192.168.1.5`. From the command prompt, I can ping the router 192.168.1.1.

---

I have a smartphone LG G3. Its operating system is Android. It is connected to **SRH-NETGEAR** as wireless for internet. From the web interface of router, I can see that the smartphone has been given IP Address as `192.168.1.6`.

---

The issue is from the desktop PC (192.168.1.10) I cannot ping the laptop (192.168.1.5).

Similarly from the laptop (192.168.1.5) I cannot ping the desktop PC (192.168.1.10).

But from the laptop (192.168.1.5) I can ping the smartphone (192.168.1.6). Similarly from the desktop PC (192.168.1.10) I can ping the smartphone (192.168.1.6).

How can I solve this problem?

---

### UPDATE:

Couple of things I forgot to mention which may be helpful in resolving this issue:

I work from home for a company. Both the desktop PC and the laptop are provided to me by the company. I use both of them for company's work.

Both the desktop PC and the laptop have the same Domain `COMPANY.LOCAL` where COMPANY is the name of the company which I have not shown for privacy reason.

The full computer name of desktop PC is `Srh-PC.COMPANY.LOCAL` while the full computer name of laptop is `Srh-HP.COMPANY.LOCAL` where COMPANY is the name of the company which I have not shown for privacy reason.

When I login to desktop PC or laptop, I use the same User name and password. The User name is `COMPANY.LOCAL\srh` where COMPANY is the name of the company which I have not shown for privacy reason.

**Windows Firewall** is turned off for `Domain network location settings`, `Home or work (private) network location settings` and `Public network location settings` on both desktop PC and laptop.

There is another software `Bitdefender` which is installed on both desktop PC and laptop.

I can make **Remote Desktop Connection** from desktop PC to laptop using its IP address `192.168.1.5`. Before making connection Bitdefender asked my permission to make the connection and I said Yes.

I cannot make **Remote Desktop Connection** from desktop PC to laptop using its name `Srh-HP`. **Remote Desktop Connection** gives me error message that it cannot find the computer "Srh-HP".

I can make **Remote Desktop Connection** from laptop to desktop PC using its IP address `192.168.1.10`. Before making connection Bitdefender asked my permission to make the connection and I said Yes.

I cannot make **Remote Desktop Connection** from laptop to desktop PC using its name `Srh-PC`. **Remote Desktop Connection** gives me error message that it cannot find the computer "Srh-PC".

Answer (score 1):

Disable or reconfigure the Windows firewall on each computer.

If you want to allow only PING, then you’ll need to allow ICMP Echo Request packets.

[Windows Firewall with Advanced Security](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754274(v=ws.11).aspx)

Comment: Windows Firewall is turned off on both desktop PC and laptop. I have updated the question with some new information.

Comment: @srh then you will have to adjust BitDefender’s firewall.

Answer (score -1):

Disable *Stealth Mode* on the desktop and laptop.

According to Microsoft:

> It is common for an attacker to use an automated scanning process to send query packets to a range of IP addresses. For each IP address, the scanning process sends packets to a range of port numbers, and the response packets are used to identify the services that are installed on the computer. For example, if a computer responds to a UDP query with an ICMP unreachable packet, or to a TCP query with a reset message, then an attacker is able to determine the existence of a computer at that IP address and an open port in Windows Firewall that can be used to reach the computer. The attacker can then use this information to attempt to exploit vulnerabilities.
>
> [Stealth Mode in Windows Firewall with Advanced Security](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd448557(v=ws.10).aspx)

You'll have to use the registry editor to disable it.

1. Open `regedit.exe`
2. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\PublicProfile`
3. Right-click in the white space on the right and click New -> `DWORD (32-bit)`

   1. Name: `DisableStealthMode`
   2. Value: `1`
4. Repeat for `PrivateProfile` and `DomainProfile` (if they exist)

<sup>Instructions adapted from [here](https://docs.storj.io/v1.0/docs/windows-firewall-with-advanced-security-stealth-mode-applies-to-windows-vista-and-server-2008-and-higher)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But stealth mode doesn’t have anything to do with the ability to ping.  Stealth mode is a desirable feature and should not be disabled.